# How to change tab bar color when it tapped

Tags: android, ios, flutter, tabbar

I want to change background color of the tabs when it tapped ?
How can I change the color
I have this test project :

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.yellow,
            indicatorColor: Colors.yellow,
            onTap: (index) {
              // Should not used it as it only called when tab options are clicked,
              // not when user swapped
            },
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: list,
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(3, (int index){
            return Center(
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` property of the controller to check which tab is currently active and listen to the controller to know when it changed.
For instance by using an `AnimatedBuilder` around the Tab widget

Answer (score 0):

These things to consider:

1. Use tab controller and check indexIsChanging
2. Wrap text inside Tab with a widget for the color change
3. Remove labelPadding

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  List<Color> tabBackground;
  List colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow];
  Random random = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    tabBackground = [Colors.blue, Colors.pink, Colors.cyan];
    tabController.addListener(() {
      if (tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        setState(() {
          tabBackground[tabController.index] = colors[random.nextInt(3)];
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        bottom: TabBar(
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          labelColor: Colors.yellow,
          indicatorColor: Colors.black,
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                color: tabBackground[0],
                child: Text(
                  'Tab 1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                color: tabBackground[1],
                child: Text(
                  'Tab 2',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                color: tabBackground[2],
                child: Text(
                  'Tab 3',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(3, (int index) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```